# Изменение регистра в input. python

Tags: python, словари

```
S = {"Да": "Молодец", "Нет": "Ты дурак"}
print(S[input("Да или Нет")])
```

Хочу, чтобы всё, что вводил пользователь, выводилось с большой буквы, но не знаю, как это сделать. Я новичок.

Comment: начинайте учить python и все у вас получится.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=upper#str.upper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `capitalize()` возвращает копию исходной строки и преобразует первый символ строки в заглавную букву, а все остальные символы строки делает строчными.

Для вашего случая код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
S = {"Да": "Молодец", "Нет": "Ты дурак"}
print(S[input("Да или Нет").capitalize()])
```

По этой [ссылке](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-capitalize-lower-upper-title/) вы сможете найти больше информации о методах, изменяющих регистр строк.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо!!!

Comment: @TerrrassaFlazer, если вам помог этот ответ, отметьте его как "принятый" (серая галка слева).